# Highcharts export button showing twice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a weird problem with highcharts:

I am calling a partial twice that uses highcharts:

```
<h3> Übersicht der User Interaction der heutigen Sendungen </h3>          
      <%= render :partial => 'shared/time_chart', :locals => {:data => @user_interactions, :entity_name => "User Interactions"} %>                  
     <h3> Übersicht der erweiterten Reichweite der heutigen Sendungen </h3> 
      <%= render :partial => 'shared/time_chart', :locals => {:data => @extended_reach, :entity_name => "Erweiterte Reichweite"} %>                  
    </h2>
```

In the _time_chart partial i use:

$(function() {
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ....

```
<div id="container<%= entity_name.gsub(" ","") %>" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
```

and on the second time I have the export button twice:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are including Highcharts exporting twice? Or you have old version of Highcharts (actual is 3.0.6). I don't see anything wrong with code you posted. Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle without RoR code?